# Need to concatenate a string to each line of ls command output in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am a beginer in Shell script. Below is my requirement in UNIX Korn Shell.

#### Example:

When we list files using `ls` command redirect to a file the file names will be stored as below.

```
$ ls FILE*>FLIST.TXT
$ cat FLIST.TXT
FILE1
FILE2
FILE3
```

But I need output as below with a prefixed constant string **STR,**:

```
$ cat FLIST.TXT
STR,FILE1
STR,FILE2
STR,FILE3
```

Please let me what should be the `ls` command to acheive this output.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't use `ls` alone to append data before each file.  `ls` exists to list files.
You will need to use other tools along side `ls`.

You can append to the front of each line using the `sed` command:

```
cat FLIST.TXT | sed 's/^/STR,/'
```

This will send the changes to `stdout`.

---

If you'd like to change the actual file, run `sed` in place:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/STR,/' FLIST.TXT
```

To do the append before writing to the file, pipe `ls` into `sed`:

```
ls FILE* | sed 's/^/STR,/' > FLIST.TXT
```

Comment: I need this is to be done at listing and redirecting command. In the question I have mentioned this.

Comment: @TechVolcano ls FILE* | sed 's/^/STR,/' > FLIST.TXT

Answer (score 8):

The following should work:

```
ls FILE* | xargs -i echo "STR,{}" > FLIST.TXT
```

It takes every one of the file names filtered by `ls` and adds the "`STR,`" prefix to it prior to the appending